# Add <td> elements into <tr> element dynamically using jquery and js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have table with few tr elements and i want to add a new td for the first tr element dynamically in my js.

Table before adding td element.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
        <tr>
    <tbody>
<table>
```

I want a table like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td> //Newly addded element
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
        <tr>
    <tbody>
<table>
```

I tried looping through tr elements and adding a new td element using jquery in my js file. Like this :

```
$('table').each((index,tr)=>{
    if(index === 0){
        tr.append("<td>B</td>");
    }
});
```

But no lock. [Object object] is being rendered in DOM in the place where I added new td.
Something like this :
[image]

Please suggest me solution to add new td in tr's dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function addCell(content, target) {
    if(content == undefined){
      content = "";
    }
    return $("<td>").html(content).appendTo(target);
  }

  addCell("B", $("table tbody tr:eq(0)"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I suspect you will have a button or other opportunities to add content. Creating a small function allows for this to be a bit easier. This function accepts the Content, what you want in the Cell, and the Target.

The last part of it will be to provide a Target. This can be an HTML Element or a jQuery Object. I provided a jQuery Object with the Selector for the TABLE > TBODY > TR (that is equal to Index 0).

You can also use it in a loop:

```
$("tbody tr").each(function(i, el){
  if($("td:eq(0)", el).text() == "A"){
    var b = addCell("B", el);
    b.addClass("dynamic");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for this. There are lots of selectors/methods you can use to target the first `td` of the first `tr`.

Any of these will work given the HTML structure in your question:

```js
$('table td:first').after('<td>B</td>');

$('<td>B</td>').insertAfter('table td:first');

$('table tr:first').append('<td>B</td>');

$('<td>B</td>').appendTo('table tr:first');
```

I'm certain there's other ways, but this gives you an idea of the approach to take.

Comment: Rory McCrossan,i like your approach. But is there  a way to loop around and add td's ?? Because I have various user case where i need to check several values before inserting the td's.

Comment: Yes absolutely. I'd suggest starting a new question about that as the one you've asked here isn't related to that problem

Answer (score 0):

I try this in pure js 
This is my code

HTML:-

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr id="myTr">
          <td>A</td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
          <td>D</td>
      <tr>
  <tbody>
<table>
```

Javascript:-

```
let myTr = document.getElementById("myTr");
let data = ['B','C'];

data.forEach(item => {
  let td = document.createElement("TD");
  td.innerHTML = item;
  myTr.appendChild(td);
});
```